# Write logs on SD card

Tags: android, permissions, android-sdcard

I want to write logs to the SD card like this

```
String filePath = "/storage/FC30-3DA9" + "/logs" + "/logcat.txt";
```

in Manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

and i request them from the user.
I can read the file from the card, but I can't write it. When I try to write a file, I get permission denied.
The path `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` leads to the internal memory of the phone. I have root.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. Since Android Kitkat removable micro sd cards are read only.

Only at Android 11 devices they are writable again.

But there is one exception: your app specific directory on the card.

Look at the second item returned by getExternalFilesDirs().

If you use Storage Access Framework instead your app can write everywhere.